why z-index doesn't work in the span attribute, it doesn't display the text above the dive
Why does my code display div.overlay over span strings?
I would like the inscription to be above the layer div.overlay
I tried changing the z-index in each attribute but it didn't help



.slideshow {
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 1920px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  text-align: center;
}

.baner {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.baner li {
  list-style: none;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #00000066;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  top: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.baner li span {
  padding-top: 180px;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  animation: imageAnimation 15s ease infinite 0s;
}

.baner li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url(../../images/fota1.jpg);
}

.baner li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(../../images/fota2.jpg);
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.baner li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(../../images/fota3.jpg);
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  13% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
<article id="top" class="wrapper style1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="slideshow">
        <ul class="baner">
          <li><span>SKUP AUT SPRAWNYCH I USZKODZONYCH <br>GOTÓWKA DO RĘKI</span></li>
          <li><span>SKUP AUT POZNAŃ I WIELKOPOLSKA <br>ZADZWOŃ</span></li>
          <li><span>SKUP AUT SPRAWNYCH I <br>USZKODZONYCH - GOTÓWKA DO RĘKI</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
<div class="overlay"></div>




<span> is an inline element so it's at whatever z-index the block that contains it is. You could try removing span from .baner li span so it's just .baner li (I'd test that but I have to go)

When you set position: absolute for .overlay and the spans inside .baner li span, they are all positioned relative to their nearest positioned ancestor. In this case, since none of their ancestors have a positioned property (position: relative, position: absolute, position: fixed), they are positioned relative to the initial containing block, which is the viewport.
To ensure that the text appears above the overlay, you need to position the spans relative to the .slideshow div, which acts as their closest positioned ancestor.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position


.slideshow {
     margin: 0px auto;
     max-width: 1920px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 450px;
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
}
 .baner {
     position: absolute;
     padding-left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 450px;
     top: 50px;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
}
 .baner li {
     list-style: none;
}
 .overlay{
     background-color: #00000066;
     width: 50%;
     height: 25%;
     top: 200px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     z-index: 1;
}
 .baner li span {
     padding-top:180px;
     font-size: 40px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     color: white;
     font-weight: 400;
     text-align: left;
     letter-spacing: 4px;
     font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
     opacity: 0;
     z-index: 2;
     animation: imageAnimation 15s ease infinite 0s;
}
 .baner li:nth-child(1) span {
     background-image : url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/19964831/pexels-photo-19964831/free-photo-of-blue-heron.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load);
}
 .baner li:nth-child(2) span {
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/12489311/pexels-photo-12489311.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load);
     animation-delay: 5s;
}
 .baner li:nth-child(3) span {
     background-image : url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/20744632/pexels-photo-20744632/free-photo-of-a-church-sits-on-top-of-a-hill-overlooking-a-valley.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load);
     animation-delay: 10s;
}
 @keyframes imageAnimation {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
    }
     13% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     25% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     37% {
         opacity: 0;
    }
     100% {
         opacity: 0;
    }
}
 <article id="top" class="wrapper style1">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="slideshow">
         <ul class="baner">
           <li><span>SKUP AUT SPRAWNYCH I USZKODZONYCH <br>GOTÓWKA DO RĘKI</span></li>
           <li><span>SKUP AUT POZNAŃ I WIELKOPOLSKA <br>ZADZWOŃ</span></li>
           <li><span>SKUP AUT SPRAWNYCH I <br>USZKODZONYCH - GOTÓWKA DO RĘKI</span></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</article>
<div class="overlay"></div>



To keep the overlay beneath the text, use the CSS span::after selector. Here's another example for clarity.


.slideshow {
     margin: 0px auto;
     max-width: 1920px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 450px;
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
}
 .baner {
     position: absolute;
     padding-left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 450px;
     top: 50px;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
}
 .baner li {
     list-style: none;
}
 .baner li span {
     padding-top:180px;
     font-size: 40px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     color: white;
     font-weight: 400;
     text-align: left;
     letter-spacing: 4px;
     font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
     opacity: 0;
     z-index: 2;
     animation: imageAnimation 15s ease infinite 0s;
}
.baner li span::after {
    content: "";
     background-color: #00000066;
     width: 50%;
     height: 25%;
     top: 170px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     z-index: -1;
}
 .baner li:nth-child(1) span {
     background-image : url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/19964831/pexels-photo-19964831/free-photo-of-blue-heron.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load);
}
 .baner li:nth-child(2) span {
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/12489311/pexels-photo-12489311.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load);
     animation-delay: 5s;
}
 .baner li:nth-child(3) span {
     background-image : url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/20744632/pexels-photo-20744632/free-photo-of-a-church-sits-on-top-of-a-hill-overlooking-a-valley.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load);
     animation-delay: 10s;
}
 @keyframes imageAnimation {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
    }
     13% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     25% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     37% {
         opacity: 0;
    }
     100% {
         opacity: 0;
    }
}
 <article id="top" class="wrapper style1">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="slideshow">
         <ul class="baner">
           <li><span>SKUP AUT SPRAWNYCH I USZKODZONYCH <br>GOTÓWKA DO RĘKI</span></li>
           <li><span>SKUP AUT POZNAŃ I WIELKOPOLSKA <br>ZADZWOŃ</span></li>
           <li><span>SKUP AUT SPRAWNYCH I <br>USZKODZONYCH - GOTÓWKA DO RĘKI</span></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</article>




Thank you for your answer :)
I would like div=overlay not to disappear but to be displayed under the inscription all the time, so that the inscriptions would be better visible against the light background of the photo.

To keep the overlay beneath the text, use the CSS span::after selector. updated the ans please check.
